# What the heck is/was this keypad for?

Tags: electrical, exterior, security

I recently noticed this keypad on our front porch.  As far as I can tell, it's not connected to anything.  Does anyone know what it was for?  A security system perhaps? Garage door?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it is a security keypad.  The DNS on the cover could be from D.N. Security Services, Inc. a company from Northern California that was acquired by Universal Services of America in 2009: http://www.universalpro.com/news2.html.

Comment: The wayback machine only has the first letter of their logo, but it looks like it matches: http://web.archive.org/web/20030909151808/http://www.dnsecurityservices.com/ (their web page from 2003). I believe this is the right answer.

Comment: Logo seems different here http://www.crunchbase.com/company/d-n-security-services

Comment: @Saxtus: that's why I went back to the Wayback machine, it looks like they changed their logo a few years ago, before they were acquired by Universal Services.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a wireless garage door keypad.

Comment: You could try taking it down and seeing if you could put new batteries in it...